# How to unsubscribe from all repos within an organisation

Tags: github

After you join an Organization on Github you automatically subscribed to all of its repos and you start getting **all** those updates you don't really want. To unsubscribe you need to go per repo and do it manually. Is it possible to unsubscribe from all repos within a particular Organisation at once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be possible since Jan. 2022, 6 years later.

> ### [Unwatch all repositories owned by a given user or organization](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-12-unwatch-all-repositories-owned-by-a-given-user-or-organization/)

> Users can now unsubscribe from all repositories owned by a given user or organization.
>
> Navigate to **[github.com/watching](https://github.com/watching)** to find a list of the repositories that you are subscribed to.
> The **`Unwatch All`** button gives you the option to unsubscribe from all repositories, or just the ones that belong to a specific user or owner.
> It will appear when you are watching all activity or custom notifications on over 10 repositories.
>
> [image: dropdown with filter -- https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/4021812/149214364-729ca426-44f6-4e75-ba88-7525aee21ae8.png?w=762&ssl=1]
>
> Clicking any of the dropdown options opens a modal to confirm unwatching repositories owned by the selected user/organization (or all repositories).
>
> [image: unwatch_dialog -- https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/4021812/149214368-c1aae5e2-25ca-46ff-8958-0c1b9a370fee.png?w=461&ssl=1]
>
> You can read more about how to unwatch a single or multiple repositories in the '**[Managing your subscriptions](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/managing-subscriptions-for-activity-on-github/managing-your-subscriptions#unwatching-repositories)**' documentation

Answer (score 32):

You can unsubscribe from all repos or one by one under https://github.com/watching

Maybe not exactly the best way but I find it useful. Hope it helps!

Comment: There's a "Unwatch all" button there now.

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to unsubscribe from all repos within a particular Organisation at once?

I don't know about *unsubscribing*, but you can go to Settings->Notification Center->Notification email and change the custom routing for the organization in question. That'll cause all e-mail for repositories in that organization to be sent to the new (possibly invalid) address.

Comment: while it's not really what I wanted, but at least it helped me to eliminate all those emails to my home address.

Comment: You can also turn off Automatic Watching, so that you don't receive messages for any repos that you haven't specifically watched. But then you have to go and watch all the repos for which you *do* want messages, which is the same problem in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

The below script helps to easily customize, add exceptions, etc.

```bash
# Make sure the personal access token has access to notifications & repo
GH_TOKEN=<TOKEN-HERE>
ORGANIZATION=<ORG-NAME>
MAX_REPO_COUNT=5000
repolist=$(GH_TOKEN=$GH_TOKEN gh repo list $ORGANIZATION -L $MAX_REPO_COUNT --json name --jq '.[].name')
echo $repolist | while read repo; do
  echo "Unsubscribing from $ORGANIZATION/$repo\n"
  GH_TOKEN=$GH_TOKEN gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/$ORGANIZATION/$repo/subscription --method PUT -F ignored=true | jq '.'
done
```